# Command \fillwithdottedlines (taken from exam documentclass) does not work in a table (Tabularray). Why? Can be fixed?

Tags: article, line, tabularray, fill

I have the following document which is a table (tabularray) which I want to full with empty dotted lines. I have defined the command `\fillwithdottedlines` as you can see in MWE. Although the command works perfectly outside `tblr` environment it does not work inside. Why this happens and how I can fix it? Please uncomment the line with this command inside the table to see the error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\makeatletter
\newlength\dottedlinefillheight
\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{9mm}

\def\fillwithdottedlines#1 {%
    \begingroup
    \ifhmode
    \par
    \fi
    \hrule height \z@
    \nobreak
    \setbox0=\hbox to \hsize{\hskip \@totalleftmargin
        \vrule height \dottedlinefillheight depth \z@ width \z@
        \dotfill}%
    \cleaders \copy0 \vskip #1 \hbox{}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[0.5\linewidth-5pt,c]X[c]},row{1,2}={1cm,m},row{3}={15cm,m},vlines,hlines}
        \SetCell[c=2]{c} \large \textbf{TITLE}                                      \\ 
        \textbf{Subtitle 1}             & \textbf{Subtitle 2}                       \\
                                        &                                           \\
        %\fillwithdottedlines{10cm}     &  \fillwithdottedlines{10cm}               \\
    \end{tblr}

\fillwithdottedlines{5cm}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just using `\dotfill` (or `\makebox[2cm]{\dotfill}` for a shorter line)?

Comment: You have right! Just wanted to know what the problem is. I also need many lines to be filled, 12 or more in each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure what is really going wrong here (and therefore this is only a partial answer), but at least one of the problems stems from the definition of `\fillwithdottedlines` which requires that a space follows the argument (because the space delimits the argument). You can check this by writing into one of the cells in the left column `\fillwithdottedlines{5cm} {}`, which at least results in no errors but still in a suboptimal output regarding vertical alignment. For some reasons I cannot explain, but probably due to the way the `tblr` is constructed, this trick does not work for cells in the right column.

A solution, however, would be to wrap the `\fillwithdottedlines` macro in a `\parbox`, for example using `\parbox{\linewidth}{\fillwithdottedlines{2cm} }`. Take care of the required space before the last closing curly brace!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm}, left=15mm, top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\makeatletter
\newlength\dottedlinefillheight
\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{9mm}

\def\fillwithdottedlines#1 {%
    \begingroup
    \ifhmode
    \par
    \fi
    \hrule height \z@
    \nobreak
    \setbox0=\hbox to \hsize{\hskip \@totalleftmargin
        \vrule height \dottedlinefillheight depth \z@ width \z@
        \dotfill}%
    \cleaders \copy0 \vskip #1 \hbox{}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = { Q[0.5\linewidth-5pt, c] X[c] },
        row{1,2} = {1cm, m},
        row{3} = {15cm, m},
        vlines,
        hlines,
    }
        \SetCell[c=2]{c} \large \textbf{TITLE}                                      \\ 
        \textbf{Subtitle 1}             & \textbf{Subtitle 2}                       \\
                                        &                                           \\
        \parbox{\linewidth}{\fillwithdottedlines{2cm} } &  
        \parbox{\linewidth}{\fillwithdottedlines{2cm} }                             \\
    \end{tblr}
    
%\fillwithdottedlines{5cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]